# Mover div para baixo

Tags: css

Eu possuo 4 divs na minha pagina, uma ao lado da outra, como eu posso fazer, para que a ultima div seja alinhada a esquerda na linha de baixo ?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Meu Codigo:

```html
     <!-- DIV 1 -->
     <div style="float: left; width: 100px; height: 50px; background-color: #CCCCCC; border-style: solid; border-size: 1; border-color: #FFFFFF;">1</div>

     <!-- DIV 2 -->
     <div style="float: left; width: 100px; height: 50px; background-color: #CCCCCC; border-style: solid; border-size: 1; border-color: #FFFFFF;">2</div>

     <!-- DIV 3 -->
     <div style="float: left; width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: #CCCCCC; border-style: solid; border-size: 1; border-color: #FFFFFF;">3</div>

     <!-- DIV 4 -->
     <div style="float: left; width: 100px; height: 50px; background-color: #CCCCCC; border-style: solid; border-size: 1; clear: Left; border-color: #FFFFFF;">4</div>

     <!-- DIV 5 -->
     <div style="float: left; width: 100px; height: 50px; background-color: #CCCCCC; border-style: solid; border-size: 1; border-color: #FFFFFF;">5</div>
```

Como ficou depois de inserir o clear:left.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Problema 2** - Após o uso do ( clear:left ).

Surgiu outro problema, eu preciso encaixar as div's conforme a imagem abaixo, eu quero fazer isso utilizando apenas CSS e sem utilizar o **margin-top**, eu preciso fazer isso utilizando alguma solução em CSS puro. Os numeros dentro das DIV's se refere a sequència em que as DIV's são exibidas pelo PHP vindo do MySql.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Obrigado

Comment: É isto que procuras? -> https://jsfiddle.net/r7Lwtu6y/

Comment: Exato, mas eu tive uma problema, como a div do final é mais larga que as outras, quando ela pula de linha, ela não esta encaixando com a de cima, fica um espaço, oque eu posso usar ? Atualizei meu topico.

Comment: Obrigado pela dica.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bom em css e html os elementos se relacionam, para está solução específica podes fazer como abaixo, entretanto pode ser necessário adaptar, sem o código inteiro não tenho como ir além...

```html
<div style="float: left; width: 100; height: 50px; background-color: #CCCCCC; border-style: solid; border-size: 1; border-color: #FFFFFF;">1</div>
 <div style="float: left; width: 100; height: 50px; background-color: #CCCCCC; border-style: solid; border-size: 1; border-color: #FFFFFF;">2</div>
 <div style="float: left;width: 100; height: 70px; background-color: #CCCCCC; border-style: solid; border-size: 1; border-color: #FFFFFF;">3</div>

  <!-- Fazer essa div abaixo se alinha a esquerda na linha de baixo -->     

 <div style="position:absolute; margin-top:55px; width: 100; height: 50px; background-color: #CCCCCC; border-style: solid; border-size: 1; border-color: #FFFFFF;">4</div>
```

Vamos tentar outro modo:

```css
div
{
    float:left;  
    height:50px;
    width:100px;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
}
#id4
{
    clear:left;
}
#id3
{
   height:102px;
   margin-top:-52px;
}
```

```html
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div  id="id4">4</div>
<div>5</div>
<div id="id3">3</div>
```

Ou mais uma opção onde defino um `width` para o `content` e assim usar o `float:right`, mas é como eu digo cada caso é um caso:

```css
#content
{
    width: 306px;
    height: auto;
}
div
{
    float:left;  
    height:50px;
    width:100px;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
}
#id3
{
    float:right;
    height:102px;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div id="id3">3</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Eu testei esse codigo, mas não funcionou muito bem, para registros automaticos vindos do banco de dados, teria como fazer sem utilizar o mar-gin-top ? algo mais automatico ?

Comment: Cara fica difícil dizer, sem termos o problema explícito, o que quero dizer é :No inicio era só jogar a div para baixo (resolve com o clear), ah mas a última div é maior,,, e assim vai... Com essas rasas informações que passou não há como ir além disso... E para falar a verdade, os dados do banco ao meu ver não deveriam influenciar, pois o front-end é o molde de exibição das informações, não importa quais sejam as informações (a grosso modo)... Então seria importante você editar e colocar mais informações, de como sua página pretende funcionar...

Comment: Pronto MagicHat, já alterei o tópico e explica com detalhes qoeu desejo. Obrigado

Comment: Repara que no seu código tem 4 divs e no exemplo visual tem 5...

Comment: Pronto Magic Hat, Alterei o código;

Comment: Veja se ficou melhor...

Comment: Então, eu reparei que a DIV 3 você jogou no final, depois da DIV 5, isso não funcionará para mim, pois as DIV's são inseridas na pagina na sequência.

Comment: Veja agora... heheh

Comment: wow, agora ficou muito loko o codigo, você pode me explicar a lógica ? Adorei.

Comment: Seguinte, como eu atribui um `width` para o caontainer com o tamanho exato das divs, quando alguma ultrapassa o tamanho ela vai para o bloco de baixo, e joguei a `div3` para a direita com o float right, se não houvesse o container para delimitar o `width` ficariam todas na mesma linha e a `div3` iria ficar a direita da janela... Repara que no container eu contei com as bordas...

Comment: Legal que deu certo... boa sorte man...

Comment: Cara, Muito obrigado Magic Hat.